# JavaFX: Can't call an Application's Label field from an anonymous class?

Tags: java, label, javafx

I'm throwing together a JavaFX application and am trying to change a Label's text by adding an anonymous class to a Listener table in the backend of my program. While the Listener will return the data it is supposed to fetch, JavaFX will crash when the label is being changed by the anonymous class.

Frontend:

```
public class App extends Application {

...

final BackendElement backendElement = new BackendElement();

...

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {

         ...

       GridPane stageContents = generateGridPane(mainStage);

         ...

       mainStage.setScene(new Scene(stageContents));
       mainStage.show();
    }


    private GridPane getGridPane(final Stage mainStage) {

          ...

        final Label labelToBeUpdated = new Label("");

          ...

        backendElement.addModelChangedListener(new ModelChangedListener() {
             @Override
             public void modelChanged(ModelChangedEvent ev) {
                 labelToBeUpdated.setText(ev.getSource()); //<- Causes verbose JFX Exception
             }
        });
    }
```

ModelChangedListener and ModelChangedEvent are just part of a custom made observer pattern. The structure definitely works since replacing the error producing line with a simple

```
System.out.println(ev.getSource);
```

will print out the desired data.

I take it the private class' label can not be called from an anonymous class. Turns out, neither can final fields in the App class. Is there a way to fix this without losing the observer pattern?

Here's the full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:237)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:397)
at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onProposedChange(Parent.java:245)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableObservableList.setAll(VetoableObservableList.java:90)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.setAll(ObservableListWrapper.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:602)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:209)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$3.changed(SkinBase.java:282)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:107)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:196)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:121)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:128)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:67)
at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:84)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:135)
at ui.App$12.modelChanged(App.java:349)
at ui.BackendElement$CustomTimerTask.informAllListeners(BackendElement.java:108)
at ui.BackendElement$CustomTimerTask.access$0(BackendElement.java:105)
at ui.BackendElement$CustomTimerTask$1.run(BackendElement.java:87)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution:
Wrap whatever you wish the listener to do with Platform.runLater() .

```
        @Override
        public void modelChanged(ModelChangedEvent ev) {

            final ModelChangedEvent event = ev;

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    labelToBeChanged.setText((String)event.getSource());
                }
            });
        }
```